# How can I make an object use its own data for spacial referencing?

Tags: javascript, class, object, animation

How can I make an object use its own spacial data rather than having to specify where it is in the canvas?

Whenever I need to specify a boundary or certain amount of pixels for an if statement, for example, I have to find where that object is on the canvas and tell the if statement where on the canvas I want the expression to be executed.

What I want to happen is to say to the object "ok, take where you are now and move yourself x pixels to the right".

Take a look at my class here for example:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  trees = new Trees(200, 200);
}

class Trees {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.a = 0
  }
  trunk() {
    noStroke();
    fill(126, 60, 1);
    rect(this.x + 3, this.y, 14, 40);
    triangle(this.x + 10, this.y + 30, this.x - 4, this.y + 40, this.x + 24, this.y + 40);
  }
  leaves() {
    fill(71, 215, 45);
    ellipse(this.x + 3, this.y - 5, 25);
    ellipse(this.x + 10, this.y - 15, 25);
    ellipse(this.x + 17, this.y - 5, 25);
  }
  shudder() {
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
      this.a = 4;
      if (this.x < this.x - 2 || this.x > this.x + 2) { // this won't work
        this.a = this.a * -1;
      }
    } else {
      this.a = 0;
    }
    this.x = this.x + this.a;
  }
}
```

You can see what I'm trying to do here.

I have succeeded in moving the object how I'd like by referencing the canvas but there must be a way of simply referencing where the object is and then offsetting that by a couple of pixels?

I don't want to do this:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  trees = new Trees(200, 200, 198, 202); // not what I want
}

class Trees {
  constructor(x, y, l, r) {
    this.x = x,
    this.y = y,
    this.l = l,
    this.r = r,
    this.a = 0
  }
  trunk() {
    noStroke();
    fill(126, 60, 1);
    rect(this.x + 3, this.y, 14, 40);
    triangle(this.x + 10, this.y + 30, this.x - 4, this.y + 40, this.x + 24, this.y + 40);
  }
  leaves() {
    fill(71, 215, 45);
    ellipse(this.x + 3, this.y - 5, 25);
    ellipse(this.x + 10, this.y - 15, 25);
    ellipse(this.x + 17, this.y - 5, 25);
  }
  shudder() {
    if (mouseIsPressed) {
      this.a = 4;
      if (this.x < this.l || this.x > this.r) {
        this.a = this.a * -1;
      }
    } else {
      this.a = 0;
    }
    this.x = this.x + this.a;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'm asking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using SVG instead of canvas?

Comment: Never even heard of it but I'll look it up! Thanks!

Comment: You should mention that you are using **Processing.js** or **P5.js**  and add the appropriate tag -- otherwise the syntax for canvas makes no sense